# How to add video to doxygen-generated html file

Tags: html, video, doxygen, mp4

I am creating an html page with doxygen and would like to add video content onto the page. Is this in general possible? I am afraid I am quite new to doxygen and could not find any information on this topic in the doxygen documentation itself.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just try to see how to add an image and otherwise just embed the relevant HTML code (with \htmlonly), probably you have to copy the video file as HTML_EXTRA_FILES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the command \htmlonly, as follows:

\htmlonly

< iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://url-to-embedded-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

\endhtmlonly

This worked well in the sense that the video was correctly shown embedded onto the web page, but funnily enough some other doxygen commands above the video stopped working.